# Does wget remember which URL has already downloaded on each job?

Tags: downloads, wget

Lets say I run wget to download a website or forum thread that contains several pages and start the download in the last page but as you know they always link to the first and last pages so wget will constantly download those pages -as they are present always- when it's curently downloading every other page?

For example I run:

`wget --mirror https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1422475&page=9`

As you see there the thread has buttons linking to the first and last pages and those two buttons are always shown so when wget downloads that URL will it download the first and last one when it goes to the page 8, and again on the page 7 and again on the page 6, and so on or it will remember it already parsed the page 1 and 9 (first and last) so it will ignore those on the subsequent pages?

I don't want to overload the server I want to archive by constantly requesting URL I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `wget` is smart enough to keep track of which URLs it has downloaded. It even has [a feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options) to take advantage of this:

> `-k`
> `--convert-links`
>
> After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing. This affects not only the
> visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to
> external content, such as embedded images, links to style sheets,
> hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.
>
> Each link will be changed in one of the two ways:
>
> - The links to files that have been downloaded by Wget will be changed to refer to the file they point to as a relative link.
>
>   Example: if the downloaded file `/foo/doc.html` links to `/bar/img.gif`, also downloaded, then the link in `doc.html` will be
>   modified to point to ‘`../bar/img.gif`’. This kind of transformation
>   works reliably for arbitrary combinations of directories.
> - The links to files that have not been downloaded by Wget will be changed to include host name and absolute path of the location they
>   point to.
>
>   Example: if the downloaded file `/foo/doc.html` links to `/bar/img.gif` (or to `../bar/img.gif`), then the link in doc.html will be
>   modified to point to `http://hostname/bar/img.gif`.
>
> Because of this, local browsing works reliably: if a linked file was downloaded, the link will refer to its local name; if it was not
> downloaded, the link will refer to its full Internet address rather
> than presenting a broken link. The fact that the former links are
> converted to relative links ensures that you can move the downloaded
> hierarchy to another directory.

You can also verify this easily enough, for example with the following two HTML files:

```
==> foo.html <==
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="bar.html">bar</a>
    </body>
</html>

==> bar.html <==
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="foo.html">foo</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

And `wget` recursively retreiving `foo.html` with debug output says:

```
...
bar.html: merge(‘http://localhost:8000/bar.html’, ‘foo.html’) -> http://localhost:8000/foo.html
appending ‘http://localhost:8000/foo.html’ to urlpos.
no-follow in bar.html: 0
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://localhost:8000/foo.html".
Already on the black list.
Decided NOT to load it.
FINISHED --2021-01-29 20:20:29--
Total wall clock time: 0.003s
Downloaded: 2 files, 122 in 0s (16.2 MB/s)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew `--convert-links` did that.